# Sort Category/taxonomy based on post count in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to sort category/taxonomy list based on number of posts it contains?

regards,
Desizner

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, can you be more specific ?

Comment: I am having a taxonomy called "Platform" and its having 12 terms in it. In that Some terms have more than 100 posts while some have less than 10. So i want to show terms which have more posts up in the list and make the terms with lesser number of posts down the list in the sidebar.

I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (September 2017) I also do it using [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) (as Ryan B) but with the following code:

```
<?php wp_list_categories( array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'order'      => 'DESC'
) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use get_categories() function and pass one of these values in 'taxonomy': 'category' (to get only categories) or 'post_tag' (to get only tags) or even remove this key and it'll get both.
Bellow we're ordering by posts counting on each category DESC.

```
<?php

$categories = get_categories([
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'orderby'  => 'count',
    'order'    => 'DESC'
]);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
   // Do something
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
    foreach (get_categories('orderby=count&order=DESC') as $category ) 
    {
    /*Some stuff here*/
    }

?>
```

For more details take  a look at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, see [wp_list_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

```
<?php wp_list_category('orderby=count'); ?>
```

is what you would use